# Make a overlay div not clickable using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, I have a semi-transparent div over my menu on a page, and I want to make that div click-through.

The CSS property pointer-events is not an option because I need to generate valid CSS. I tried with:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

with no luck, the div on the "bottom layer" doesn't be clicked.

Here is my code in a simplified version:

```
<div id="menuContainer">
<div id="menu">
//here comes all the items of my menu
</div>
</div>
<div id="shadow">
</div>
```

the css:

```
#menuContainer {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
z-index: 0;
height: 200px;
}
#menu {
width: 300px;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10; 
top: 160px;
}
#shadow {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 150px
height: 200px;
}
```

is not an option for me to change the z-index or the layout, just I need when I click the shadow, the click is "re-transmitted" to the menu.

Comment: This is not possible, there is no substitute for pointer-events in non-supporting browsers as far as I know. You will have to change your site layout, and z-index will not help you with clicking thru an element. Only thing I can think of is catching the mouse pointer position and trigger corresponding elements behind the covering element, but that is overly complicated for something that is basicly a design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using jQuery's click() function?

http://api.jquery.com/click/

You could catch the click event on the topmost element, simulate a click on the element below, and then *return* to stop the original click.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$('#shadow').click(function() {
    $('#menu').trigger('click');
});
```

The shadow element is passing the click event on to the menu.

If you need to relay the mouse position as well, check out the [Mouse Position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) tutorial.

Comment: but if I trigger the click to the menu, it automatically trigger the events to the inside elements? I have:
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>lorem ipsum</li>
<li>lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Nope! only the #menu element will be triggered, unless you somehow figure out what part of the menu is behind your shadow element and trigger that specific element instead.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @adeneo that this whole approach is probably a design flaw. Why do you need to put something over your menu? Could you just set the background image of the menu items, or something like that?